# Which will be the java regex to parse the following log file

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to parse a log file in java. The log files contains information about a call transaction. The lines that I'm interested in and also the information within are marked in bold within the log line entry example. For the following one I need to extract, the Status and phone number:

> Aug 15 20:35:22 GMT 2012 tropo109.orl.voxeo.net TROPO 138595 0
>   e467547d3333724bdd52635bbb713e77 1 d607eb64fb3bfbfd273a55f4b121b903
>   SimpleOutgoingCall[+17877058826/null->+17877260664/null] :
>   [**TRANSFER**,**+17877260664**]

and from this line I need to obtain the phone number and the total calling time.

> Aug 15 20:35:22 GMT 2012 tropo109.orl.voxeo.net TROPO 138595 0
>   e467547d3333724bdd52635bbb713e77 1 d607eb64fb3bfbfd273a55f4b121b903
>   Logging CDR
>   {"call":{"SipSessionID":"ss_jzto5yd4jruv","SessionID":"e467547d3333724bdd52635bbb713e77","CallID":"d607eb64fb3bfbfd273a55f4b121b903","ParentSessionID":"none","ParentCallID":"none","DateCreated":"Wed,
>   15 Aug 2012 20:34:14 +0000","DateUpdated":"Wed, 15 Aug 2012 20:34:14
>   +0000","AccountID":"138595","Called":"**+17877260664**","Caller":"+17877058826","PhoneNumberSid":"unknown","Disposition":"Script
>   ended","Status":"Success","StartTime":"Wed, 15 Aug 2012 20:34:14
>   +0000","EndTime":"Wed, 15 Aug 2012 20:35:22 +0000","Duration":"**67950**","Flags":"out","RecordingDuration":"0","Network":"SIP","Channel":"VOICE","ApplicationId":"392671","ApplicationType":"groovy","ServiceId":"1291899","StartUrl":"http://hosting.tropo.com/138595/www/outboud-web2ivr.groovy","BrowserIP":"10.6.69.109","PPID":"461"}}

So in general I'll need to parse a file and within different log  lines entries get the  call status and duration. Any pointers?

UPDATE:
I got the code to get the first part, any pointer on how to get the second and have just one compiled expression that either will find (phone,status) or (phone,callduration) within a log entry line?:

```
private static void matchParts( String aText ){

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\[(\\w(\\w)*),(\\+\\d{11})\\])");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aText );
  String phone;
      String status;
  while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println("phone:" +matcher.group(3) + ", status: "+matcher.group(1) );
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you happen to try with any regex already to extract this information? or are you looking for resources to learn about RegEx? If so, this is a good place to start with: https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Have a look @ http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html, packed full of useful regex info.

Comment: Can you give use more information on what your trying to accomplish? the regex `+17877260664|67950` would technically give you what your asking for but i doubt its general enough for what you are really trying to do.

Comment: It's not for that specific number or time duration, it's for any number, or status or duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:

```
private static void matchParts(String line){
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(": \\[(\\w+),\\*(\\+\\d{11})\\*]");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
   String phone;
   String status;
   while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("phone:" +matcher.group(2) + ", status: "+matcher.group(1) );
   }
}
```

For the second:

```
private static void matchParts(String line){
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Called\":\"(\\+\\d{11}).*\"Duration\":\"(\\d+)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
   String phone;
   String status;
   while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("phone:" +matcher.group(1) + ", duration: "+matcher.group(2) );
   }
}
```

I use this very handy tool: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html when it comes to finding regexes.

**EDIT:**
If you are looking for 1 regex instead, it could be something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w+),\\*(\\+\\d{11})\\*].*?Called\":\"(\\+\\d{11}).*?\"Duration\":\"(\\d+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: thanks for the input! One question if i want to combine both into one pattern that will look line by line if either match the first pattern or the second, how could be done?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the portion of the log after ":" in the first one looks like a JSON Array and the portion of the log after CDR in the second section looks like a JSON Map. You could use a simple JSON library in any language of your choice to convert those log sections and access the required information in a structured way: http://json.org

Answer (score 0):

Is this all one line or multiple lines?

If the first one is multiple lines, then:

```
String line = yourline
if(line.indexOf("SimpleOutgoingCall" != -1)
{
    String data = line.split(":")[1];
    String status = data.substring(1, data.indexOf(",")); 
}
```

The second one looks like the first two are different lines, but the {{ ... }} block is one line" If so:

```
String line = yourline
String data = line.split(",");
String called, duration;
for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
{
    if(data[x].indexOf("Called") != -1)
        called = data[x].split(":")[1];
    if(data[x].indexOf("Duration") != -1)
        duration = data[x].split(":")[1];
}
```